# Resuming a suspended UWP application from a Desktop application

Tags: uwp, process, windows-runtime, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

As the title suggests I am curious to discover a programmatic solution that allows for WIN32 desktop applications to resume a suspended UWP application. I am writing a small process management app that allows for suspending & resuming processes however metro applications simply don't respond to the Win32 API calls to SuspendThread and ResumeThread. Does anyone know how to resume a UWP application from a Desktop application? Any hints here would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resume a suspended app using the `AppResourceGroupInfo.StartResumeAsync` API. This can be called either from a desktop app, or a UWP app. When calling from a UWP app you need to declare the `appDiagnostics` capability.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appresourcegroupinfo.startresumeasync

Comment: Hi Stefan, your information is much appreciated. Do you happen to have any Win32 app calling example, i.e> using GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary()) on whichever assembly needs to be loaded? Ultimately I'd like to do this from a Win32 c++ application

Comment: LoadLibrary isn't the way to go here. This is a WinRT API. Here is an older blog post explaining how to call those from a Win32 app. This still works roughly the same way in new versions of VS, too.
https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/

Comment: Thanks Stefan I appreciate the information you've provided me

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I'm trying this from a WPF app and it just doesn't do anything. Pretty sure [my code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nwbSMj) is fine because if I switch it to StartSuspendAsync() and have it called while the UWP app is in foreground, that actually works just fine. Does the target UWP app require the appDiagnostics capability?

Comment: @SeanO'Neil Not sure why this doesn't work. Might be best to start a new question and include repro details.